# Xcode: App icon is always in project root directory

Tags: ios, xcode, icons

When I drag and drop the app icons to the project summery in Xcode, it copies the icons to the projects root directory. Is there a possibility to put the icons in another directory inside the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do it...

1. You can manually do an entry in projectName-info.plist in the key Icon files,
   Icon files is an array in this array one item you add i.e. Item 0 and the value should be your image file name.
2. Just name your icon image to "icon.png" and include it in your project(anywhere you want).
   Xcode will take care of it.

Comment: Way 2 works, but it seems that way 1 works only for iOS5 or earlier

Answer (score 1):

No, the compiler requires them to be in the root directory.